# How to downgrade flutter plugin using Android Studio?

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I have upgraded to the latest version of the flutter plugin but breakpoints stopped working and I need to downgrade to another version:
[image]

But there is no option for downgrading(only disable and uninstall/install).

How can I downgrade it using Android Studio or dev tools?

Answer (score 2):

In your terminal run these code:

```
flutter downgrade <yourVersion> // for example: flutter downgrade 3.0.4
flutter doctor
```

Comment: Why 3.0.4 and in the marketplace is 70.2.2?

Comment: I know the latest version is 3.3.5 but what 70.2.2 is?

Comment: could you show me  where did you see 70.2.2? you can find flutter version [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/sdk/releases?tab=windows)

Comment: Look at the screenshot I have added in the question flutter is 70.2.2>

Comment: @SimpleCode sorry I don't know what is it. Definitely it is not flutter version.